# How can I position widgets inside a layout?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm having trouble with spacing widgets in a QVboxlayout. I have this code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        win_w, win_h = 250, 1
        self.setGeometry((1920 - win_w) // 2, (1080 - win_h) // 2, win_w, win_h)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 12))
        
        self.central_widget()

    def central_widget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        group_box1 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Group Box')
        v1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        text_edit1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        v1.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button'))
        v1.addWidget(text_edit1)
        
        group_box1.setLayout(v1)
        
        grid.addWidget(group_box1, 0, 0)
    
        widget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Running this brings up this window:

[image]

Adding this line `v1.setSpacing(100)` changes it to this:

[image]

Is there any way to make it add the spacing horizontally? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `alignment` keyword argument for [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget):

```
v1.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button'), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
```

As already suggested, you should carefully read the documentation about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), including *all* the listed QLayout subclasses and all their methods. You can do some experiments on your own with them also in [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html), so that you can better understand how they work by directly seeing the results.

Comment: Thanks! just what I needed. As for reading the docs... well lets just say it's a little intimidating, and I don't always know where or what to look for, but I will try next time. Ty anyway!

Comment: Qt is a powerful and complete toolkit, and while it's widely used and there are lots of available and complete resources, it's learning curve is not fast, and it takes even years in order to be able to "fully" understand it. I started using it more than 5 years ago, and I still find out things I didn't know yet from time to time. Luckily, the documentation is very well written and comprehensive; I completely understand your intimidation, that's normal for a huge library as Qt is, and that's one more reason to begin studying with patience. Good luck, and have fun ;-)